# mergeMap cancels previous HTTP calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a dialog that when opened dispatches an action to preload data for form controls inside the dialog. The action is picked up by an effect that in turn returns an array of new actions to preload the data for each `id` in the array that is passed to the original action.

```
@Effect()
preloadReferenceData$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(PRELOAD_REFDATA)
  .pipe(
    map((action: PreloadRefData) => action.payload),
    mergeMap(ids => {
      const actions: Action[] = [];
      ids.forEach((id) => actions.push(new LoadRefDataForId(id)));
      return actions;
    })
  );
```

Normally, I use the `mergeMap` operator to successfully dispatch multiple new actions from an effect, though this is the first time I'm dispatching multiple actions of the same type, and it's the first time I've experienced that the XHR calls get cancelled. I would have suspected the use of `switchMap` in the case where the XHR calls are cancelled, but not now when I use `mergeMap`.

These is the content of `actions`

```
LoadRefDataForId {payload: "2441", type: "[Refdata] Load RefData"}
LoadRefDataForId {payload: "7612", type: "[Refdata] Load RefData"}
LoadRefDataForId {payload: "9411", type: "[Refdata] Load RefData"}
```

and this is taken from the network log

[image]

The effect that handles the `LoadRefDataForId` action

```
@Effect()
loadRefDataForId$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_REFDATA_FOR_ID)
  .pipe(
  map((action: LoadRefDataForId) => action.payload),
  switchMap((id) => this.service.loadRefData(id)
    .pipe(
    map((occupations) => {
      return new LoadRefDataForIdSuccessful({ id: id, occupations: occupations } as RefDataPayload);
    }),
    catchError((err, caught) => {
      console.log(caught);
      return caught;
    })
    ))
  );
```

Why are the XHR cancelled, even though I'm using `mergeMap`?

Comment: Can you add the code for the effect that handles LoadRefDataForId Action? this one isnt in charge of sending any sort of request

Comment: Added the code @Jota.Toledo! I tried changing that `switchMap` to a `mergeMap` which makes it all work, but I don't understand why. Aren't there three separate observables that are merged, and the use of `switchMap` in any of them should only cause effect to that specific stream?

Comment: And why the close flags? Yes, it's a `Why doesn't this code work?`-type of question, but with the big difference that I argue how and why it should work, and with a reasoning question in the end.

Comment: Personally I flagged cause of the missing effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cancelations are caused by this effect:

```
@Effect()
loadRefDataForId$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_REFDATA_FOR_ID)
  .pipe(
  map((action: LoadRefDataForId) => action.payload),
  switchMap((id) => this.service.loadRefData(id)
    .pipe(
    map((occupations) => {
      return new LoadRefDataForIdSuccessful({ id: id, occupations: occupations } as RefDataPayload);
    }),
    catchError((err, caught) => {
      console.log(caught);
      return caught;
    })
    ))
  );
```

By using `switchMap` in it, you are telling that only the last `LoadRefDataForId` action that passes through the `actions$` stream should be considered/processed.

Change it to:

```
@Effect()
loadRefDataForId$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(LOAD_REFDATA_FOR_ID)
  .pipe(
  map((action: LoadRefDataForId) => action.payload),
  mergeMap((id) => this.service.loadRefData(id)
    .pipe(
    map((occupations) => {
      return new LoadRefDataForIdSuccessful({ id: id, occupations: occupations } as RefDataPayload);
    }),
    catchError((err, caught) => {
      console.log(caught);
      return caught;
    })
    ))
  );
```

Comment: I *kind of* understand why, but I still don't grasp exactly why the `switchMap` doesn't work. Isn't it possible to use `switchMap` in any other observable stream that's merged in a `mergeMap`?